# TranslocoLocale pipes injected into a service causes unit test errors

Tags: angular, transloco

How can I test a service that uses TranslocoLocale pipes (TranslocoDecimalPipe, TranslocoDatePipe, etc.)? I could obviously mock the pipes myself but I shouldn't have to.

TranslocoLocale pipes in my component templates work correctly in unit tests.
Using the pipes in a service, by injecting them in the constructor, causes the unit tests to break.
It will either complain that the pipe has no provider, or that ChangeDetectorRef has no provider.

In the example below, My service uses the TranslocoDecimalPipe. In my test I get the error:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[L10nTestService -> TranslocoDecimalPipe]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[L10nTestService -> TranslocoDecimalPipe]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslocoDecimalPipe!
```

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { createServiceFactory, SpectatorService } from '@ngneat/spectator/jest';
import { TranslocoModule } from '@ngneat/transloco';
import { TranslocoDecimalPipe, TranslocoLocaleModule } from '@ngneat/transloco-locale';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
class L10nTestService {
  decimalValue: string;

  constructor(private translocoDecimalPipe: TranslocoDecimalPipe) {
    this.decimalValue = translocoDecimalPipe.transform(1234567890.123456);
  }
}

describe('L10ntestService', () => {
  let spectator: SpectatorService<L10nTestService>;
  const createService = createServiceFactory<L10nTestService>({
    service: L10nTestService,
    imports: [
      TranslocoModule,
      TranslocoLocaleModule.init()
    ],
    providers: [TranslocoDecimalPipe]
  });

  beforeEach(() => spectator = createService());

  it('decimal value should be transformed', () => {
    expect(spectator.service.decimalValue).toBe('1,234,567,890.123');
  });
});
```

Comment: I assume the Transloco required config, imports and providers are into the TranslocoModule and it's init() method. Check that you are not missing anything in the test case setup, you can compare it with you AppModule. Hope that helps!

Comment: I've tried it with/without the TranslocoRoot module, which contains the configs.
I've also tried it with/without providing the pipes in the serviceFactory. it still fails to find the pipe

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work with [ng-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks). Just like this:

```
imports: [
  ...,
  MockModule(TranslocoLocaleModule),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I mocked my TranslocoPipe and check that it is being called with the right arguments.

I want to test:

```html
<p [innerHTML]="'MY.TRANSLATION.KEY' | transloco : { date: expectedDeliveryDate, time: localizedExpectedDeliveryDate }"></p>
```

So in my test I used:

```
const fakeTransform = (...args: string[]) => JSON.stringify(args);
const translocoPipeMock = jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(fakeTransform);
```

Using `ng-mock` and the [MockBuilder](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockBuilder) I replace the original pipe with the mock using:

```
.mock(TranslocoPipe, translocoPipeMock)
```

Then I can just assert like this:

```
expect(translocoPipeMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('MY.TRANSLATION.KEY', {
  date: theMockedDate,
  time: theMockedTime,
});
```